# Change the font and font weight for lightning-output-field

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, slds

How do I change the font size, font weight of the text from `lightning-output-field` ?

```
<lightning-output-field class="outputFont" field-name="Protocol__c" data-id="trialProtocol"
                                value={trialRecord.Protocol__c} variant="label-hidden" required>
</lightning-output-field>
```

CSS:

```
.outputFont {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```

But the CSS is not getting reflected. What is the other way of imposing styles in `lightning-output-field`?

Comment: Did you take a look at [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#Styling-Hooks-Overview)?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because of [shadow dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) that doesn't let styles of parent leak to its child. In short, you can't change the styles of a component outside of it. Salesforce recently introduced [Styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) to help developers style base components as they want which are based on the concept of css-variables.

`--lwc-inputStaticFontSize &  --lwc-inputStaticFontWeight` are the hooks for input `font-size & font-weight`.
So, put values of these css variables in your component. And they'll do the magic themselves.

```
:host{
   --lwc-inputStaticFontSize: 14px;
   --lwc-inputStaticFontWeight: bold;
}
```

Read more about shadow dom [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243725/understanding-shadow-dom-in-lightning-web-components)

Comment: Can you tell on what it is for lightning-output-field?

Comment: It's the same. `lightning-output-field` uses a disabled input under the hood.

Comment: How would you apply this selectively so that only some of the lightning fields are modified?

Comment: @JeffCallahan You can put it under a css class and add it on the lightning element. Styles in `:host` are applied to root of the component.